# How to add individual layer of WMS group layer to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, wms

I am attempting to add a single WMS layer that is part of a WMS service group layer.  I am writing code to do this using ArcObjects in C# .Net.  So far I have been unsuccessful.  I can either only add the whole group layer, or I can add the individual WMS sub-layer but the full group is also still added.

Here is the code I have tried.  I have allowed the user to select a layer from a list, and this code is trying to only add that selected layer.

```
    IWMSGroupLayer wmsMapLayer = new WMSMapLayerClass();
    IWMSConnectionName connName = new WMSConnectionNameClass();

    IPropertySet propSet = new PropertySetClass();
    propSet.SetProperty("URL", "http://www.___________________?");

    connName.ConnectionProperties = propSet;

    IDataLayer dataLayer = (IDataLayer)wmsMapLayer;
    dataLayer.Connect((IName)connName);

    IWMSServiceDescription serviceDesc = wmsMapLayer.WMSServiceDescription;
    IWMSLayerDescription groupDesc = serviceDesc.LayerDescription[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < groupDesc.LayerDescriptionCount - 1; i++)
    {
        IWMSLayerDescription layerDesc = groupDesc.LayerDescription[i];

        if (layerDesc.Title == lstWMSLayers.SelectedItem.ToString())//Checking if this is the selected layer
        {
            ILayer newLayer;
            IWMSLayer newWMSLayer = wmsMapLayer.CreateWMSLayer(layerDesc);
            newLayer = (ILayer)newWMSLayer;
            wmsMapLayer.InsertLayer(newLayer, 0);

            IMxDocument mxDoc = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
            mxDoc.FocusMap.AddLayer((ILayer)wmsMapLayer);
            IActiveView activeView = (IActiveView)mxDoc.FocusMap;
            activeView.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

In ArcMap I get the following tree of layers

- WMS Service Group Layer

  - Selected WMS Layer
  - WMS Group Layer

    - All the layers that are part of the service...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to add that layer (and that layer only) through the ArcMap user interface?

Comment: Yes, when I add an individual layer through ArcMap, I get the WMS Service Group Layer, and then only the one WMS layer, nothing else.  So it should be possible through ArcObjects too right?

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear the WMS Service Group Layer before adding the single WMSMapLayer.

```
wmsMapLayer.Clear();
wmsMapLayer.InsertLayer(newLayer, 0);
```

Note that this will remove all group/map layers from the WMS Service Group Layer, so if you're adding more than one, it might be advisable to not call wmsMapLayer.Clear() in the body of your loop. I haven't tested as I'm only adding a single layer, but perhaps instead, loop through groupDesc.LayerDescriptionCount and grab all the layerDesc objects that match your criteria, then Clear() and add the selected WMS layers back in.